# Getting the latest row in a specific time span on a daily basis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing query that uses the 'with CTE' function. This query returns my desired results, however, the query also returns duplicate values within a specific time span on any given date. To give you an example, the query returns results like this:

```
rn | NAME     MACHINE   SUPERVISOR    LAST_UPDATE
1  | NAME_1   T_001     SUP_1         2015-10-14 09:55:26.637
2  | NAME_2   T_002     SUP_2         2015-10-14 11:54:07.087
3  | NAME_2   T_002     SUP_3         2015-10-14 12:02:31.663 
4  | NAME_3   T_003     SUP_4         2015-10-14 22:53:28.253 
5  | NAME_4   T_005     SUP_4         2015-10-14 09:55:47.293
6  | NAME_3   T_003     SUP_3         2015-10-15 01:59:00.000
7  | NAME_3   T_003     SUP_3         2015-10-15 10:19:00.000
```

Now, this is the rule that I need to achieve: I need to get the latest rows with the same Name and Machine on a 9AM-9PM and 9PM-9AM time span. This is the result that I need to achieve:

```
rn | NAME     MACHINE   SUPERVISOR    LAST_UPDATE
1  | NAME_1   T_001     SUP_1         2015-10-14 09:55:26.637
3  | NAME_2   T_002     SUP_3         2015-10-14 12:02:31.663  
5  | NAME_4   T_005     SUP_4         2015-10-14 09:55:47.293
6  | NAME_3   T_003     SUP_3         2015-10-15 01:59:00.000
7  | NAME_3   T_003     SUP_3         2015-10-15 10:19:00.000
```

Take note that row 2 was removed because row 2 and row 3 has the same Name and Machine and since they are within the 9AM-9PM time span, I only need the latest version which is row number 3.

Look at row 4, 6 and 7. These rows have the same name and machine but only row 4 and row 6 are the ones within the 9PM-9AM time span. So only row 6 was retained. Row 7 was untouched because it's unique (name and machine) on its own time span.

I would really appreciate if you could help me on this one. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @tbl table(id int, NAME varchar(100),  MACHINE  varchar(100), SUPERVISOR varchar(100),  LAST_UPDATE datetime)

insert @tbl (id, NAME,  MACHINE, SUPERVISOR,  LAST_UPDATE)
values(1, 'NAME_1',  'T_001','SUP_1','20151014 09:55:26.637'),
(2,'NAME_2','T_002','SUP_2','20151014 11:54:07.087'),
(3,'NAME_2','T_002','SUP_3','20151014 12:02:31.663'),
(4,'NAME_3','T_003','SUP_4','20151014 22:53:28.253'),
(5,'NAME_4','T_005','SUP_4','20151014 09:55:47.293'),
(6,'NAME_3','T_003','SUP_3','20151015 01:59:00.000'),
(7,'NAME_3','T_003','SUP_3','20151015 10:19:00.000')


    select *,DATEADD(HOUR,9,CAST(CAST(t1.LAST_UPDATE as date) as datetime)), DATEADD(HOUR,33,CAST(CAST(t1.LAST_UPDATE as date) as datetime))
    from @tbl t1
    where not exists(select *
                     from @tbl t2
                     where t2.id<>t1.id
                           and t2.NAME=t1.NAME
                           and t2.MACHINE=t1.MACHINE
                           and t2.LAST_UPDATE>=t1.LAST_UPDATE
                           and t2.LAST_UPDATE>=DATEADD(HOUR,9,CAST(CAST(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t1.LAST_UPDATE)>9 THEN t1.LAST_UPDATE ELSE DATEADD(DAY,-1,t1.LAST_UPDATE) END as date) as datetime))
                           and t2.LAST_UPDATE<DATEADD(HOUR,33,CAST(CAST(CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,t1.LAST_UPDATE)>9 THEN t1.LAST_UPDATE ELSE DATEADD(DAY,-1,t1.LAST_UPDATE) END as date) as datetime))
                     )
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. But most of the trouble comes from the part where I need to get the latest rows (with the same name and machine) within a specific time span. In my example, I've used the 9AM to 9PM and 9PM and 9AM time span.

Comment: @MarcusL. I updated the answer, but according to your explanations row 6 shouldn't be in the result set.

Comment: row 6 should be there. In the example, rows 4,6 and 7 has the same name and machine. However, since I only want the latest row (with the same name and machine) WITHIN a 9AM-9PM and 9PM-9AM(of the following day), row 6 is retained and row 4 is not included because row 6 is the latest row from 9PM to 9AM. Row 7 is untouched because it's already in another time span. If, however, there's another row that exists within 9AM-9PM with the same name and machine as row 7, then Row 7 will be omitted and another row with latest date will be retained.

Comment: @MarcusL. Of course it's too late, but I corrected the query )